# error when defining function with an if

Tags: function, clojure, classcastexception

We have a simple function definition:

```
(defn calculate [d x y]
  ((if (and (== d 1) (== x 1) (== y 0))
     1
     0)))
(println (calculate 1 1 0))
```

But that results in this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke    (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at jline.ConsoleRunner.main(ConsoleRunner.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
    at user$calculate.invoke(main.clj:13)
    at user$eval5.invoke(main.clj:17)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:6465)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:6902)
    at clojure.lang.Compiler.loadFile(Compiler.java:6863)
    at clojure.main$load_script.invoke(main.clj:282)
    at clojure.main$script_opt.invoke(main.clj:342)
    at clojure.main$main.doInvoke(main.clj:426)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:401)
    at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:161)
    at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:518)
    at clojure.main.main(main.java:37)
    ... 5 more
```

(BTW, line 13 is the line with `if` and `and`).

The same with vectors:

```
(defn calculate [vectorr]
  ((if (and (== (vectorr 0) 1) (== (vectorr 1) 1) (== (vectorr 2) 0))
     1
     0)))
(println (calculate [1 1 0]))
```

This results in:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

... the same.

And with a map:

```
(defn calculate [mapp]
  ((if (and (== (mapp :d) 1) (== (mapp :x) 1) (== (mapp :y) 0))
     1
     0)))
(println (calculate {:d 1 :x 1 :y 0}))
```

Results in the same message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

We think is has something to do with `if`, or the comparisons. We have tried it with normal arguments, a vector as an argument and with a map as such and obviously, the error stays the same.

We've also tried many other variations without greater insights on the actual problem.

Comment: Generally-speaking, if you see multiple left parens next to each other, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @Alex - very good tip! in the cases when you genuinely want this (i.e. applying a returned higher order function) then it's still useful to do a double-take....

Comment: Note that `if` and `and` are **not** functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an extra pair of parentheses around your function body, which means you want to call the result of the `if` (which is either 1 or 0 — i.e. a long).

It should be:

```
(defn calculate [vectorr]
  (if (and (== (vectorr 0) 1) (== (vectorr 1) 1) (== (vectorr 2) 0))
     1
     0))
```

Comment: Well yes, I understand. Stupid parentheses, love them! -- That does away with the problem. Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score -1):

The extra parenthesis cause your program to crash becasuse they change the return type of your expression.  By enclosing something in parenthesis, in clojure, you wind up wrapping an expression as a function.  Then, your program which references that function's output is now actually referencing the function itself.

I find that, 90% of the time, if I get a class cast exception in clojure, its because I have created a cloSure on accident.

Comment: "By enclosing something in parenthesis, in clojure, you wind up wrapping an expression as a function." That's not quite right. By enclosing something in parentheses you call it as a function - you don't wrap it in anything and you certainly don't create a closure.

Comment: Thank you too! Could also just be that we're spending too much time in front of our screens and get stupid ...